# Read an app setting in my .Net 5 application without using DI

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, appsettings, .net-5, app-startup

I created an MVC application using .Net 5.
Then I created a custom Attribute should read some settings from `appsettings.json`.
Here a working solution:

```
public class MyCustomAttribute : Attribute
{
    public MyCustomAttribute(string key)
        : base()
    {
        IConfiguration conf = new ConfigurationBuilder()
           .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
           .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
           .Build();
        
        var value = conf.GetValue<string>(key);

        ...
    }

    ...
}
```

It works, but **I do not think it is the correct solution**. I try to explain why.

In the `Program.cs`, beforse the host is builded, the `startup` class is instantiated:

```
var builder = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args); builder
    .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
    {
        webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();

    });
```

If I inject the `IConfiguration` to the stratup, I can get the `appsettings.json` values:
[image]

I think that from now, I have the appsettings.json and conseguently the configuration in memory.

So it seems really strange to me that in my custom attribute I must read the setting from the file again!
The question is: How can I read the in-memory configuration inside my custom attribute?
Is my consideration correct?

Thank you.

**EDIT**

I have found another solution, but I still does not like it:

I have modified the `startup.cs` ctor in this way:

```
public Startup(IWebHostEnvironment environment, IConfiguration configuration)
{
    this._environment = environment;
    this._configuration = configuration;

    AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetData("conf", this._configuration);
}
```

And the ctor of `MyCustomAttribute` in this way:

```
public class MyCustomAttribute : Attribute
{
    public MyCustomAttribute(string key)
        : base()
    {
        var conf = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetData("conf") as IConfiguration;
        var value = conf.GetValue<string>(key);

        ...
    }

    ...
}
```

Also this solution works. But I hope something out-of-the-box in .Net 5 exists. I would expect the normal behavior when the configuration is read, would be something similar to my solution.

Comment: Attributes must have their constructor parameters supplied where they're applied, therefore it does not support constructor dependencies provided from DI.

Comment: It's not what I meant. I have edited the question with another consideration.